# use Waypoint with React to execute a function after scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jquery-waypoints

I have a counter component that counts up to a number on the page. I need it to run ones the user scrolls to that point on the page. How do I do that with Waypoint? Or is there another solution?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Waypoint from 'react-waypoint';

var Counter2017 = React.createClass({

   getInitialState: function() {
      return {visionElapsed: 0};
   },
   tick: function() {
      if (this.state.visionElapsed < 125) {
      this.setState({visionElapsed: this.state.visionElapsed + 1});
      }
   },
   componentDidMount: function() {
      this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 15);
   },
   componentWillUnmount: function() {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
   },
   render: function() {
      return (
         <span>{this.state.visionElapsed}</span>
      );
   }
});

export default Counter2017;
```

Answer (score 2):

You insert your waypoint where you want it to be (it is a DOM element).

So you would have something that looks like this:

```
<div>
  <AnyComponents />
  <Waypoint
    onEnter={() => this.interval = yourInterval}
  />
</div>
```

Of course you can check if there is already an interval so you don't override it. You can also set an `onLeave` props on the Waypoint component. I suggest you to read about it here: https://github.com/brigade/react-waypoint

Comment: I'm new to React, is there an actual example with my component above of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)`. In that method you will get notified about change in state. Invoke there what you need when user reaches the point.

More in docs: 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is using the [react-waypoint](https://github.com/brigade/react-waypoint) lib